# Lightning tag request

Tags: feature-request

There should be a tag for [lightning](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lightning).

(also I think there should be a separate tag [new-tag](/questions/tagged/new-tag) for posts like this, but maybe it's included in [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)?)

Comment: what questions do you see on the site that this is a good fit for. I cant think for a class of questions that have lightning at their core.

Comment: There are a few questions about lightning protection and manipulation which have tags like [tag:high-voltage] and [tag:current]. There is also a tag [tag:thunderbolt] which I think could have [tag:lightning] as a synonim.

Comment: For those that dont know, the way I reference a tag is \[tag:lightning] which will give you [tag:lightning]

Comment: Where is @stevenvh when we need him?

Answer (score 2):

The reason these requests are so uncommon is because it requires a really low reputation (300) to be able to propose new tags. The newest users aren't always the best judges on how the site works, so I think this is reasonable. Feel free to request the tag in the comments to your question.

Answer (score -2):

We have [thunderbolt](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/thunderbolt), although it's underutilized.

The word *lightning* is more commonly used word.  But there are 2 words that sound similar:

- *lighting* - illumination
- *lightening* - reducing weight

English language is frugal, when it comes to spending letters on making words.